# обрезать число, которое, например, заканчивается кучей ненужных нулей (regex qt c++)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Как можно обрезать число, которое, например, заканчивается кучей ненужных нулей?
Есть такое выражение:

```
^[0]{0}[1-9]\\d+\\.?\\d+|[0]{1}\\.\\d+$
```

P.S. еще нескромный вопрос - можно ли данное выражение как-нибудь оптимизировать? А то боюсь, что немного кривовато вышло.

Comment: приведите пример числа, и как его надо обрезать.

Comment: Константин, формата два (по выражению, которое выше):
1. 1213344.79879000000
2. 0.00945000000000000
нули убрать, которые в конце

Comment: А как выглядит ваш код?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qRinAj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А могу я предложить решение без регулярных выражений?

```
std::string strip_trailing_zeros(std::string &str)
{
    return str.substr(0, str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1);
}
```

Мне кажется что это должно быть побыстрее.

**P.S**

А вот вариант, удаляющий нули с начала и конца строки, а также полностью удаляющий дробную часть вместе с точкой, если она содержит только нули, вдруг кому понадобится.

```
std::string strip_zeros(std::string &str)
{
    size_t sep_pos, l_pos, t_pos;
    sep_pos = str.find_first_of(".,");
    if (sep_pos != std::string::npos) {
        t_pos = str.find_last_not_of('0');
        if (t_pos == sep_pos) {
            t_pos--;
        }
    } else {
        t_pos = str.length() - 1;
    };
    l_pos = str.find_first_not_of('0');
    if (l_pos != std::string::npos && l_pos == sep_pos && l_pos > 0) {
        l_pos--;
    } else if (l_pos == std::string::npos) {
        l_pos = str.length() - 1;
    }
    return str.substr(l_pos, t_pos - l_pos + 1);
}
```

Пример http://ideone.com/V9cuqN

Comment: Мне кажется, [`std::string s1 = "000";` не должно вызывать проблем](http://ideone.com/AyoWan).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, вы правы, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ:

Один и более ноль в конце строчки.

```
[0]+$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Z4Pug-cr3a6qUUEL)